# Unable to see .txt files in iFile

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, ios

Am using iPhone 3Gs running on 6.1.3.
My problem is that whenever am trying to open any .txt file in iFile, it shows weird symbols and characters. Am sure the files are not any binary files.

First I thought this could be a problem with a particular .txt file I want to open, but all files with .txt extension (So far I have tried nearly 50 .txt files) show strange characters and symbols.

Is this problem with iFile or do I have to change encoding language? If so please help me how to do it. I have removed and reinstalled iFile many time to see if the problem is resolved. But no use.

Comment: I doubt you're using UTF-8?

Comment: If so, how to change encoding?

Comment: This sounds exactly like an encoding mismatch, but I can't seem to figure out how to fix it in iFile.

Comment: No Solutions yet!!!???? :(